Can door slabs be replaced simply by taking measurements and ordering new ones?
I live in a mid-80s built house with hollow interior doors and brass door knobs. The door frames and trim are still in excellent shape so we’re thinking new solid slab doors as replacements would do the trick.
Is it really as easy as just measuring the doors we have now and ordering exact size replacements?

Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We can't decide what you are capable of doing. That part of your question is off topic. Also off topic are recommendations of brands and sources. If you have a more specific question about the task itself, please revise to ask that. Skip the appearance assessment as it's not relevant. I've started revisions for you.

Not that solid doors will be far heavier, and a load on the hinges and jamb when open. You might need to add another hinge or reinforce the jamb, or not.

You can often simply order new door slabs to upgrade interior doors. However, there are a few gotchas to keep in mind.

Hinge size and location rarely match perfectly, even with the same brand. There are two ways to work around this. You can take precise measurements to the mortises (always from the top of the slab) and pass that to the retailer, or you can order unmortised doors and transfer locations yourself when you do the mortising*.

Door latch bolt locations can also vary somewhat. There's maybe 1/4" of vertical tolerance in a typical strike plate at most. Beyond that and you're cutting and grinding to make it work. Be sure they'll align well when you order.

Because of this variability, jambs and stops may need to be reset or adjusted to restore appropriate margins and gaps.

New and old paint or stain almost never match perfectly. Plan to repaint the jambs and casing with whatever you use on the door slabs. If you're staining, do some testing on multiple wood samples to be sure you'll be happy with the outcome.

Solid doors are heavy. Therefore it's critical that jambs be hung with best practice in mind (not just floated on casing nails). This often means screws which penetrate framing, either behind the hinges or through them. The jamb should be well shimmed at the top and bottom hinge locations to prevent unintentional movement when screws are tightened.

For the same reason, door stops need to be adequate. Hinge pin stops won't work well, at least in singles. Use two or more. Wall bumpers must have framing behind them or you'll destroy the drywall over time. Any interference with other doors or objects should be anticipated and dealt with.



* Mortising may sound intimidating, but it's not difficult with the right tools and a little know-how. You'll want a router with a suitable bit and a jig. Practice on scrap two-by lumber first.

If you have a real door shop nearby, they’ll probably take your old hollow core doors, and match the hinge/knob in new solid core doors. The cost won’t be free but it probably won’t be too surprising either.
